# how to get the running coordinates of a map while panning the map in V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get the running coordinates (of the center of the map) when a user pans the map .Is there any way to do so ? I successfully got the center coordinates using `mMap.getCameraPosition().target;` and I can also get the coordinates while the user taps ,but I have no idea on how to get the running coordinates while panning the map.

I would like to know if there is a tutorial or code snippet available for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setOnCameraChangeListener%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener%29).

If that is not enough, let me know.